# Best Practice To send Big JSON Data to Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

Node js : I am taking a survey which have 21 question init and answer should be in written text so the Json became very big. My question is how should I send my data to the backend should I send the whole JSON or I should store it in the file and then send it what is the best practice for this ? (Front End : JQuery And Backend : NodeJS )

Comment: If your backend allows a huge amount of data at once, then just send it (Using POST method)!

Comment: 1 answer of the question can be a 100 word answer

Comment: I can't store data one by one survey allows user to go back ad change their answer so I have to send all those answer at once

Comment: @user9346670 So? What makes you think that "one-by-one" solution doesn't allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "very big". Cause I seriously doubt that your users will write answers that weight more then say 50Kb. Note that average kindle ebook weights ~2.5Mb with ~300 pages (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-file-size-of-an-e-book). And even this size is not really big for a request.

Anyway, to improve UX it is worth considering splitting the survey into multiple pages and sending each page to the server one-by-one. For that you have to store those pages on the server side of course (possibly with timeouts in case a user decides he won't continue).

Comment: no the data is not that big  all answer may contain 100 or 200 words and user can go back end change the answer so I don't think I should send data to server again and again

Comment: can I send it like this.   $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        url:"",
        data:{'q1':'answer 1','q2':'answer 2', ......},   
        success: function (html) {

          $('#add').val('data sent sent');
          $('#msg').html(html);
        }
      });

Comment: @user9346670 There's nothing stopping you from reading and writing documents partially. Here by "document"  I understand a set of `(question, answer)` pairs. You can see examples of that everywhere, even here at StackOverflow. When number of answer (or comments) becomes big paging kicks in automatically. And yet you can still modify the content. Finally: the way you send it to the server is irrelevant, assuming it is POST, not GET. There are serveral reasons for that. Both size limitations and security.

Comment: yes it is post  I copied it from some where and didn't pay attention to it and Thank you for your answer